# Onebox of blog posts is broken

Tags: bug, status-deferred, chat, blog, onebox

Trying to onebox new blog posts from https://stackoverflow.blog fails, the message stay as a plain link to the blog post and does not onebox anymore. [Example](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7774028#7774028).

<s>Oneboxing of older posts is still fine. [Example](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7774032#7774032).</s>

In August 30<sup>th</sup> 2023, the blog got [a new look and feel](https://stackoverflow.blog/2023/08/30/new-refresh-stack-overflow-blog-update/), aka major redesign. Side effect of this, is that now onebox of its posts is 100% broken, for any post. This can be clearly seen [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=stackoverflow.blog&user=-2&room=89), and [here](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=stackoverflow.blog&user=-2&room=7).

Can this please be fixed and onebox of blog posts to become possible again?

Comment: works okay evidence: https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/7857174#7857174 so it is definetly on the blog that something goes wrong.

Comment: [Onebox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/onebox): *"A feature of Stack Exchange chat, "oneboxing", automatically inlines some links that are posted on a single line by themselves."*

Comment: @This_is_NOT_a_forum yes. Why do you repeat the tag wiki? Any issue with it?

Comment: This is in our brand design team's backlog, but since it is relatively low-priority and we don't have an estimate for when it'll be worked on, I'm setting the status to [tag:status-deferred].